# Homepage has redirect loop

Tags: 7, redirection, commerce

One of my sites has started to have a redirect loop that just happens on the homepage. Not the secondary pages though. (Drupal 7 - Commerce Kickstart)

```
Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.
```

Some days it does this, some days it doesn't. I feel like it magically fixes itself during the week and on the weekend it breaks. Is there any way to can find out where it is trying to redirect itself to and remedy it? Would the redirect location/error be logged somewhere I could check?

Comment: Hello and welcome. I'm afraid it's more of a server issue. First thing first, you should investigate if PHP is even started when this occurs. If it's not, it means it is your webserver or proxy issue, not Drupal at all. Anyway, we cannot debug it for you. Not "don't want". Literally can not. And the data you posted in your question is not enough to post an answer. Ask your sysadmin to help you gather more data, maybe?

Comment: Good to know it's a server issue and not drupal. Somewhere I can at least start looking. I have done a bit of terminal. Are there any commands I could run to find out more info since I'm in the dark?

Comment: Do you have an access log? Try to test **if** PHP was running. If it was, it still might be a Drupal issue. But to know, you need to test it on a webserver server level. Access attempts from one IP, repeated fast, are what you're looking for. but I can't tell you how to read these logs. I usually ask my sysadmin to do this for me, I know just enough to know what to ask him for.

Comment: I don't have access to the CPanel to the server. But I do have SSH root. I have never dug for server logs manually. Where would I look for these? /var/? It's a linux server. If not I'll just need to get access to server CPanel and go from there. Thanks a ton for the info thus far.

Comment: @Mołot I got root access and accessed the logs. This is the errors I have that is repeated over and over.

`PHP Warning:  Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini`
-- and then the 2nd error -- 
PHP Fatal error:  Unsupported operand types in public_html/dev/profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/search_api_db/service.inc on line 970`. 

I increased the max_inout_var limit. That should be a temp fix till I talk with the Drupal Commerce Kickstart community and figure out this other primary issue. Thanks again for help and direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found follow errors in php logs:

```
PHP Warning:  Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini 

PHP Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in public_html/dev/profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/search_api_db/servic‌​e.inc on line 970
```

Got the redirect loop to stop after increasing the max_input_vars to 9000. I feel it's more of a bandaid fix though. So I'm taking this further into the Commerice Kickstart community.